# superfish+ slicknav not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slicknav

I have a problem on menu of website,this menu have more section and in desktop version is `suddivise` in two part , the first is normal menu the second use jquery `superfish` for drop-down menu in desktop.

In mobile use only slicknav, http://slicknav.com/

every work fine , but have a problem , if example open the menu in desktop and after try to resize the screen of desktop the `superfish` not switch with `slicknav`, only if reload the page work and load correct class.

The same in viceversa:

If open menu in slow screen and after try to open not switch to `superfish`

in practice should change class to a same `<div class="">` to use in desktop `superfish` and `slicknav` in Mobile

ii have used this script but not work

```
<script>

function resize() {
if ( $(window).width() < 739) { 
$("#nullo").toggleClass('sf-menu cambioclasse2');
}
else {
$("#nullo").toggleClass('sf-menu sf-menu');
}
}
$(window).on("resize", resize);
resize(); // call once initially

</script>
```

The `class="cambioclasse2 "` in a class i have used for annulled the class of `superfish "sf-menu"`

Menu in desktop:

```
<div id="header" class="clearfix">
    <ul id="top-menu">

    <ul id="nullo" class="sf-menu">
      <li>
        <a class="tito" href="/amministra/"><img src="/inc/files/images/adminplus.png"></a><div class="ams">AMMINISTRA</div>

           <ul>
                                        <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_commerciale/" title="">
                              Commerciale                           </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_eccellenze/" title="">
                              Eccellenze                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_aree/" title="">
                              Aree                          </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_contabile/" title="">
                              Contabile                         </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_certificazioni/" title="">
                              Certificazioni                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_compensi/" title="">
                              Compensi                          </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_trattative/" title="">
                              Trattative                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_club/" title="">
                              Club                          </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_guida/" title="">
                              Guida                         </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_pagine/" title="">
                              Pagine                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_mailing/" title="">
                              Mailing                           </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_report/" title="">
                              Report                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_batching/" title="">
                              Batching                          </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_temi_seo/" title="">
                              Classificazione                           </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_visite_pagine/" title="">
                              VIsite pagine                         </a>
                        </li>
                                   </ul>
      </li>
</ul>


          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                <a href="/vacanze_weekend/">
                Vacanze             </a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="/matrimoni/">
                Matrimoni               </a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="/meeting/">
                Meeting             </a>
            </li>

          </li>

                    <li><span class="current-lang">ita</span> | <a href="/en/" title="English - Luxury hotels and historical boutique hotels">ENG</a></li>
```

menu in mobile:

```
<div id="header" class="clearfix">
    <ul id="top-menu">

    <ul id="nullo" class="sf-menu">
      <li>
        <a class="tito" href="/amministra/"><img src="/inc/files/images/adminplus.png"></a><div class="ams">AMMINISTRA</div>

           <ul>
                                        <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_commerciale/" title="">
                              Commerciale                           </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_eccellenze/" title="">
                              Eccellenze                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_aree/" title="">
                              Aree                          </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_contabile/" title="">
                              Contabile                         </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_certificazioni/" title="">
                              Certificazioni                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_compensi/" title="">
                              Compensi                          </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_trattative/" title="">
                              Trattative                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_club/" title="">
                              Club                          </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_guida/" title="">
                              Guida                         </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_pagine/" title="">
                              Pagine                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_mailing/" title="">
                              Mailing                           </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_report/" title="">
                              Report                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_batching/" title="">
                              Batching                          </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_temi_seo/" title="">
                              Classificazione                           </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_visite_pagine/" title="">
                              VIsite pagine                         </a>
                        </li>
                                   </ul>
      </li>
</ul>


          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                <a href="/vacanze_weekend/">
                Vacanze             </a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="/matrimoni/">
                Matrimoni               </a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="/meeting/">
                Meeting             </a>
            </li>

          </li>

                    <li><span class="current-lang">ita</span> | <a href="/en/" title="English - Luxury hotels and historical boutique hotels">ENG</a></li>
```